# continuously incrementing values of label by pressing the button

Tags: ios, touch, cocos2d-x, multi-touch

[image: Here is my Main screen]

(Newbie in IOS Dev) This is my main screen, This screen is .ccbi file and buttons are images which I've linked in my code and implementing the methods. what I am doing is when I click the Plus button value increments by one same on negative button case. but each time I've to click the button to increase/decrease the value. I want when I press the button the values should keep increasing until I un-touch the button.? How can I do this? I read somewhere that it could be done using CCLayer TouchBegin(); But I could not find material to help me understanding the mechanism. any suggestions?

Comment: This question is not about Xcode.

Comment: Do you also want to be able to increment by 1 for a normal touch down followed quickly by a touch up, or do you just want the continuous update as long as the finger is down??

Comment: yes, if I click for one time then it should increment by one, but If I keep my finger over the button then it should keep increasing until finger is removed.

Comment: I've edited my answer to use a gesture recognizer which should work with your images.

Comment: I working on cocos2d-x, so I need code in C++. and C++ doesn't support UIEvent, UIViewController..

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that cocos2d-x was C++.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do it using a timer and two IBActions.

Declare a Timer and Two IBAction like:

```
@property (nonatomic) NSTimer *timer;
- (IBAction)inc:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender;
```

And implement the method like:

```
- (IBAction)increment:(id)sender
{
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self selector:@selector(inc) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
- (IBAction)stop:(id)sender
{
    [_timer invalidate];
}

- (void)inc
{
    //Increment and set the text value here
}
```

**The most important thing:**

Connect the `increment:` function to the `touch down` event of your `UIButton` and `stop:` function to the `touch up inside` event

Comment: this works in the case if you have a .xib file, but my main screen file is .ccbi

Comment: it's worth also saying that you could call `[self inc]` method on `touch up inside` if you want to increment by one on single touch or tap especially if the time interval is more than 0.1

Answer (score 1):

You can just have a method that's trigged with "touch down" instead of the usual "touch up inside". That method would start a timer that would update the label at whatever rate you want. You would have another method on touch up to stop this.

**After Edit:**

If you have images rather than buttons, you'll have to do this with a gesture recognizer. I created a subclass of UITapGestureRecognizer and overrode touchesBegan and touchesEnded which each call a delegate method that is handled by the view controller class.

RDTapper.h

```
@protocol TapperTapped <NSObject>

-(void)touchedDownOnTapper;
-(void)touchedUpOnTapper;

@end

@interface RDTapper : UITapGestureRecognizer

@property (weak,nonatomic) id <TapperTapped> delegate;
```

RDTapper.m

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.delegate touchedDownOnTapper];
}


- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.delegate touchedUpOnTapper];
}
```

ViewController.m

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSTimer *aTimer;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSDate *startTime;
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet RDTapper *tapper;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tapper.delegate = self;
}

-(void)touchedDownOnTapper {
    self.startTime = [NSDate date];
    [self performSelector:@selector(startIncrement) withObject:nil afterDelay:.3];
}


-(void)startIncrement {
    self.aTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self selector:@selector(incr) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)touchedUpOnTapper {
    if ([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.startTime] < .3) 
        self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.label.text.integerValue +1];
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    [self.aTimer invalidate];
}

-(void)incr{
    self.label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", self.label.text.integerValue +1];
}
```

So this will increment by one with a normal touchDown/touchUp sequence, but do a continuous increment, after a slight delay if you hold your finger down.

Comment: Oh I forgot to mention it that my screen is .ccbi file, button actually are images added over a CCLayer.

Answer (score 0):

Well about the holding down, and continuously incrementing, i'm not fully sure about, but to increase the text label just edit the text attribute.

```
-(IBAction) increase {
textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", number];
}
```

Comment: If you read my question again, I've mentioned there that I am already increasing the value. What I need to do is to increment the value Continuously.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **UIControlEventTouchDown** & **UIControlEventAllTouchEvents** control states of UIButton they could help you achieve what you want to do.

Check out this enum

```
typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSUInteger, UIControlEvents) {
    UIControlEventTouchDown           = 1 <<  0,      // on all touch downs
    UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat     = 1 <<  1,      // on multiple touchdowns (tap count > 1)
    UIControlEventTouchDragInside     = 1 <<  2,
    UIControlEventTouchDragOutside    = 1 <<  3,
    UIControlEventTouchDragEnter      = 1 <<  4,
    UIControlEventTouchDragExit       = 1 <<  5,
    UIControlEventTouchUpInside       = 1 <<  6,
    UIControlEventTouchUpOutside      = 1 <<  7,
    UIControlEventTouchCancel         = 1 <<  8,

    UIControlEventValueChanged        = 1 << 12,     // sliders, etc.

    UIControlEventEditingDidBegin     = 1 << 16,     // UITextField
    UIControlEventEditingChanged      = 1 << 17,
    UIControlEventEditingDidEnd       = 1 << 18,
    UIControlEventEditingDidEndOnExit = 1 << 19,     // 'return key' ending editing

    UIControlEventAllTouchEvents      = 0x00000FFF,  // for touch events
    UIControlEventAllEditingEvents    = 0x000F0000,  // for UITextField
    UIControlEventApplicationReserved = 0x0F000000,  // range available for application use
    UIControlEventSystemReserved      = 0xF0000000,  // range reserved for internal framework use
    UIControlEventAllEvents           = 0xFFFFFFFF
};
```

Comment: my main screen is .ccbi screen so I can't use any of these methods.